# How do i make my blender poly structure symetrical?

Tags: modeling

The blender poly structure is not symmetrical from the top. I've tried symmetrize and snap to symmetry. It doesn't do anything.

I have discovered that sculpting causes the objects symmetry to basically go berserk (yes even if I sculpt symmetrically.) (at very minimal amounts though).

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would help if you took a photo that more clearly showed your mesh, and what was wrong with it.

Comment: Unless I zoom in a ridiculous amount, it won't show. The file is there for reference.

Comment: Try clearing the rotation in object mode with ALT-R. The scale is already set to 1, but the rotation is all over the place! It seems to sculpt ok once that is reset.

Comment: Thank you your advice sounds very useful. I tried doing as you said but nothing happened. I think I'm doing something wrong? I selected the object so that it is yellow and pushed alt r but the only thing that appears is the clear rotation pop up in the bottom left corner.